# What’s the difference between these three sentences?

Tags: prepositions, difference

1. In 1951, when Woo was only five years old, his family fled China and **arrived in** Hong Kong.
2. In 1951, when Woo was only five years old, his family fled China and **arrived at** Hong Kong.
3. In 1951, when Woo was only five years old, his family fled China and **arrived** Hong Kong.

Comment: The third sentence is wrong, because 'arrive' is an intransitive verb and takes no object. I think the other two sentences are correct.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, 'arrived **in**' is used for large places such as countries, cities or towns, whilst 'arrived **at**' is used for smaller places like specific buildings, sites or roads etc. Therefore, I would say that only the first sentence is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your examples:

> 1) In 1951, when Woo was only five years old, his family fled China and arrived **in** Hong Kong.

They arrrived ***within*** a location.

> 2)In 1951, when Woo was only five years old, his family fled China and arrived **at** Hong Kong.

They arrived ***at the border*** of Hong Kong, not necessarily within the confines of the location.

> 3)In 1951, when Woo was only five years old, his family fled China and arrived Hong Kong.

Would generally be understood to mean either 1) or 2) depending on additional context. It is a form of shorthand, but is grammatically not complete.  For example,

> The flight departed London yesterday and arrived Hong Kong an hour ago.